# AWS EC2 - Web App on Multiple EC2 with load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2

Currently I have setup my web application on my 2 instance (ec2). Both instance have same web module and also SSL certificate. 
And then I also have setup 1 load balancer for both instance for high availability.
But I was wondering on domain name part. Because both instance have different IP, and right now I only assign 1 IP instance into our domain provider.
So basically do I need provide both instance IP into my domain provider? Sorry I was newbie on this domain part :(

Answer (score 0):

wasabiz, since you are a newbie, I would suggest going with AWS Beanstalk path.

To answer your question.

You can use Route53 to create/import your domain Name. The domain can point to DNS name of the Loadbalancer.  From there LB will route the traffic to your EC2 instances. You need to introduce the autoscaling layer and move the EC2 instances inside it. So that the auto scalaing requirements can be fulfilled.   All these options are configurable in AWS BeanStalk.

You have options to generate TSL certificates in AWS which is free to be used in AWS infrastructure. Otherwise, if you already have a certificate, you can import the certificate into AWS through AWS Certificate Manager and use it where ever needed, eg:load balancer.